# Можно ли поставить паузу и продолжить?

Tags: python

Как правильно вставить time.sleep во вторую строку кода,чтобы во время движения курсора по траектории были паузы,допустим,1 секунду? Или каким-то другим способом можно сделать такое?

```
pyautogui.dragTo(333, 787, button='left') #нажатие левой кнопки мыши 
pyautogui.drag(50, 0, 3, button='left') # пермещение зажатой левой кнопки мыши по траектории 50 горизонтально
```

Comment: кто нажимает мышку? кто кого тащит? о чем речь вообще? перечитайте свой вопрос и решите, поймет ли его кто-то, кроме вас.

Comment: Поставил комментарии,во второй строке кода нужно сделать паузы

Comment: Если я правильно понял то добавьте `time.sleep(1)`, где 1 это время в секундах. А вообще научитесь формулировать мысли, ибо вопрос действительно не понятен.

Comment: Да,немного запутанно написано,как правильно вставить time.sleep в эту строку pyautogui.drag(50, 0, 3, button='left')

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать `mouseDown` и `mouseUp`:

```py
import time
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(333, 787)

pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
pyautogui.move(25, 0, duration=0.25)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.move(25, 0, duration=0.25)
pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое